# How Can I Make Test Names Unique When Test Classes Derive from Abstract Base Test Classes

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, vstest

We use Visual Studio Enterprise (2019) and Azure DevOps CI build/release pipelines to execute a set of tests against an existing "system" to identify regression issues when the system undergoes development.

The test solution includes projects having model-based test-classes that derive from abstract test classes.  This way the same test methods can be evaluated over-and-over-and-over on different models.  Some examples of the repetitive tests are shown below as screenshot from VS test manager window:

[image]

Here's an example of how the test classes inherit the test code:
[image]

...and here's a look at the abstract base test class:
[image]

So **here's the problem/question I am trying to resolve**: When the CI build pipeline executes the tests, the results are shown in Azure DevOps Test Runs. Because of inheritance, the test names are duplicated over and over again making it difficult to isolate which Model classes have the regression issues needing to be resolved. Notice the repeating test names in the test run results window:

[image]

What I want is to be able to dynamically change the runtime name of the tests so that each test is unique. **As a band-aid** we have included `GetName().name` in the asserts so it shows up in the failure message, but that's not really a full fix because the messaging text doesn't filter, sort or chart effectively.

Is there any way to override the test name at execution time (or before) so that we can differentiate the inheritance-based tests?

Comment: I am afraid that you can't do it. You need to download test result file to check it through Visual Studio.